# What's the best practice for multiple types of ID? - Normalization Question

Tags: database-normalization, erd

If I have three types of ID, say employee ID, customer ID, supplier ID, and they all have a set of attributes. Should I just have them in the same table or is there a better way to organize them? Can I just name the primary key "ID" to include all thee? - Is that an accepted practice? I learned that generally primary key and foreign key should keep the same name so maybe that's not allowed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you represent inheritance in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579079/how-can-you-represent-inheritance-in-a-database)

Answer (score 0):

I would say that if they all have the same attributes, then they would all belong in the same table under a generic `ID` column.

For example, a `person` table:

- id
- name
- type (`employee`, `customer`, `supplier`)

This would allow you to query each of the individual types with something like:

```
SELECT * FROM person WHERE type = customer
```

If there is information unique to each type of ID, you can denote attributes by linking them off to another table. For example, say an `employee` has some more detailed additional information (like a `manager`). Both the `employee` *and* the `manager` would sit in the same generic table, and you would create a ['bridging table' (or 'associative entity')](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity) to link them together:

`employee_manager` bridging table:

- employee_id
- manager_id

This way you can find all employees who belong to a certain manager with:

```
SELECT * FROM employee_manager WHERE manager_id = 1
```

And cross-reference them to the `person` table with a `JOIN` based on the type of information you wish to retrieve.